# Exact scope of modal logic?

Tags: modal-logic

Is modal logic the logic of necessity, possibility, and impossibility alone, or the logic of truth, falsity, necessity, possibility, and impossibility?

In other words, is modal logic concerned with modal statements only, or concerned with both modal statements and truth-functional statements?

Comment: A current article in the Online Encyclopedia of Philosophy, [*Modal Logic: A Contemporary View*](http://www.iep.utm.edu/modal-lo/) surveys the many interpretations and connections of modal logic. Its scope far exceeds your broader alternative. I don't think anyone would be comfortable stating that "the **exact** scope of modal logic is thus & such".

Answer (score 0):

See [What is Modal Logic?](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#WhaModLog):

> Narrowly construed, modal logic studies reasoning that involves the use of the expressions ‘necessarily’ and ‘possibly’. However, the term ‘modal logic’ is used more broadly to cover a family of logics with similar rules and a variety of different symbols [including logics for belief, for tense and other temporal expressions, for the deontic (moral) expressions such as ‘it is obligatory that’ and ‘it is permitted that’, and many others.]

Usually, *modal* propositional logic is built "on top" of *classical* (i.e. truth-functional) propositional logic.

See e.g. George Boolos & John Burgess & Richard Jeffrey, [Computability and Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=0LpsXQV2kXAC&pg=PA327) (4th ed - 2002): **27.1 Modal Logic**, page 327-on:

> *Modal* sentential logic adds to the apparatus of ordinary or ‘classical’ sentential logic one more logical operator, the box $\square$, read ‘necessarily’ or ‘it must be the case that’. One more clause is added to the definition of sentence: if $A$ is a sentence, so is $\square A$. [...]
>
> A modal sentence is said to be a *tautology* if it can be obtained from a valid
> sentence of nonmodal sentential logic by substituting modal sentences for sentence letters. Thus, since $p ∨ \lnot p$ is valid for any sentence letter $p$, $A ∨ \lnot A$ is a tautology for any modal sentence $A$.